Does Brachyura pick moves to try and hit Shanoa?
The Castlevania Wiki on Brachyura says that it acts differently depending on Shanoa's position:

If Shanoa is on the left side of its pincer, it will attempt to punch her.
If Shanoa is on the right side of its pincer, it will insert it into its smaller pincer, build up energy, and let it go, slamming the back of the larger pincer into the wall.

But from fighting it more than 10 times, sticking to the bottom left of the screen, with the final battle being practiced conjuring cubes and throwing axes...
It seems like Brachyura picks its moves randomly? For example, it will try to do the stored energy smash, but I never been on the right side of the screen? It's only a danger because the storing phase does create a danger zone on the lower left.
So does Brachyura have a Shanoa-position-dependent attack choice? Or does Shanoa's position only matter for where the Acidic Bubbles go, possibly?
